# OSX / Eclipse / JDK / Can't run HelloWorld from bash

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, bash, classpath

I'm trying to get back into Java development on OSX 10.9.5, and having a very basic problem getting a trivial program to run on the command line.

I've installed a recent JDK:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)**
```

I've installed Eclipse, version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

I created a simple Java program within Eclipse, and I configured it to use the JRE version 1.8.0_45 that I installed.

I can run a simple HelloWorld program from this project within the IDE:

```
package repotools.repotool;

public class RepoToolApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

It shows the expected output within the Eclipse console.

I cannot get this to run from my bash shell.  When I attempt to run it, I get the common error:

```
$ ls
RepoTool.class      RepoToolApp.class
$ java RepoToolApp
Error: Could not find or load main class RepoToolApp
$ java -cp ./ RepoToolApp
Error: Could not find or load main class RepoToolApp
$ export CLASSPATH=.
$ java RepoToolApp
Error: Could not find or load main class RepoToolApp
$
```

I don't have a .bashrc file, but it seems I can execute java and javac fine because they are in my path.  There is no CLASSPATH set by default, but my understanding is that should not be a problem.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Thanks very much!

Comment: `cd ../..`, up to the directory above `repotools/repotool`, then run `java repotools.repotool.RepoToolApp`.

Answer (score 3):

The directory in which you execute `java` should be the one containing the root of the package containing the class. In this case:

```
$ cd ../..
$ java repotools.repotool.RepoToolApp
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html:

> By default, the first argument without an option is the name of the class to be called. **A fully qualified class name should be used.**